# xunit Reseed Fixture LocalDb Before Each Unit Test Cases c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public class SampleActivityTests :  IClassFixture<TestFixture>
{
  private readonly TestFixture _testFixture;

  public SampleActivityTests(TestFixture fixture)
  {
      _TestFixture = fixture;            
  }
```

There are four test cases.

For each test cases same fixture is used

There is also update test cases.

After update test cases runs,  dbcontext data moved to Get test cases. There asserting will fail.

So i decided to refresh (refill) fixture i.e dbContext every time when each test case is called.

I used dispose() after each test cases but when it goes to another test cases it fails. Please help me to refresh fixture data.

Comment: When you have a LocalDb then you did not write a **unit test**. This is called an **integration test**. Both have the same lookalike but different rules. f.i. *unit tests* can run in parallel, *integration tests* maybe

Comment: HI Sir, here i am refering localdb as fixture. It is just like seed data. Ya my agenda is for each test case, fixture data should be called or it should be fresh. not reusing same data used in other test case. Thanks